# PostgreSQL: insert from multiple select?

Tags: postgresql, sql

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to insert field values into a table using multiple selects from various other tables? Something like the following SQL (I have over simplified my original problem). I don't want to perform two individual insert operations.

```
insert into table_1 (name, id)
(select name, id from table_2 limit 1),
(select name, id from table_3 limit 1);
```

Comment: Yes, you need to use union between your selects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [UNION or UNION ALL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-union.html) to build one result from your two selects:

```
insert into table_1 (name, id)

select name, id from table_2 limit 1 
UNION
select name, id from table_3 limit 1;
```

UNION will remove the duplicated rows from the union, UNION ALL will include all.